How to generalise non-asymptotic Cramer-Rao lower bound for unbiased estimators in semiparametric models?
We all know the classic Cramer-Rao bound which specifies a lower bound of any unbiased  estimator's variance in a parametric model. Note that this bound is non-asymptotic in a sense that it is valid for all sample number $n$ and don't need to consider asymptotic variance.
I did a survey on semiparametric models but all semiparametric literature I found only consider the asymptotic variance lower bound of estimators.
Hence, I am wondering is it possible to get the counterpart of Cramer-Rao bound in semiparametric models. This variance lower bound can only valid for all unbiased estimators, but should be non-asymptotic.
Any relevant thoughts and literature are welcome!

I think you end up with the same semiparametric information bound. This shouldn't be too surprising, as the semiparametric information bound is so closely related to the CR bound.
Start with finite-dimensional parameters estimable at $\sqrt{n}$-rate -- that is, the semiparametric model is specified by $(\theta,\eta)$, and the piece you're interested in is $\theta$, which is finite-dimensional and estimable at $\sqrt{n}$-rate.
We have the ordinary CR bound for a parameter $\theta$ for all parametric submodels of a given semiparametric model, so the lower bound on variance of a unbiased estimator $\hat\theta$ must be at least the supremum of the CR bound over parametric submodels for that sample size. Call that variance $nV_{\text sup}$. If $V_{\text{finite}}$ is the thing you want, then $V_{\text{finite}}\geq nV_{\text{sup}}$
Now, $nV_{\text{sup}}$ is the usual semiparametric information bound, and standard semiparametric theory tells us $nV_{\text{sup}}$ is achievable asymptotically for reasonably well-behaved models, so it can't be far from sharp as a bound. That is, we can't typically expect $\liminf V_{\text{finite}}> nV_{\text{sup}}$.  We can't really hope to get a non-asymptotic CR bound that's better than the asymptotic one by more than some function converging to 1 (eg $(n-1)/n)$)
On the other hand, if $\theta$ is not $\sqrt{n}$-estimable then you typically won't have any unbiased estimators that are any good at all.
Arguing towards a contradiction, suppose $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator and the data size is $n$.  You can split the data into halves $(n/2,n/2)$, estimate $\theta$ on each half, and average the two estimates.  If the estimates are unbiased, $\hat\theta_n$ will be unbiased and its variance on a sample of size $n$ will be half that on a sample of size $n/2$, implying $\sqrt{n}$-convergence.
This still leaves the case of parameters estimable faster than $\sqrt{n}$, and I don't really have any ideas there.

Would it possible to find a more explicit representation of $V_{\text{sup}}$? Since finding parametric submodels is not an easy task.

I don't know. The asymptotic bound is the variance of the efficient influence function, but that's not actually a lot more explicit
